# Tapping on the app widget does not start the service after a force quit

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an app widget. After performing a force quit the widget does not respond. I  have to restart the application by manually starting the main application activity.

How should it behave generally, after a force quit, can we start the service from Widget after a force quit or we can start the service only from the main application after a force quit?

Comment: What exactly is a "force quit"? Do you mean clicking "Force Stop" on the app's screen in the Settings app?

Comment: yes I meant force stop@CommonsWare

Comment: OK, please provide a [mcve] and show us what your `PendingIntent` looks like that you are attaching to your app widget.